# Hosting a Website at home

Tags: apache, port, wampserver

I am using WAMP with Apache 2.4.9 on Windows 8 64 bits.
I've set up port forwarding (for port 80) on my router and set up a static IP to my computer on my network.
I can access my website from my computer and from my network. But I cannot access it externally by typing my IP on the browser URL Bar.

I believe my ISP is blocking port 80 or preventing me to host a web server. How can I avoid such blocking?

Comment: You should ask over in "Server Fault". But usually you cannot.

Comment: Are you using the right IP address? You should connect using your external IP address (check https://www.whatismyip.com/), not your computer's local IP address.

Comment: http://ping.eu/port-chk/ check it.... did you change the localhost refs in httpd.conf? also check the Order Allow,Deny statement..

Comment: I am using my external IP Address.

Comment: Also note that your IP is subject to change unless you're paying for a one that's dedicated.

Comment: I haven't changed my localhost refs and the port is closed according to the site on your link.

Comment: well find a open port and edit httpd.conf to listen to that port e.g. `listen 8080`, then change servername localhost to servername your ip..  and replace the allow order deny with `Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all`

Comment: There is no such Order Allow,Denny statment on my httpd.conf file. Am I missing something?

Comment: you have a new version of apache, you should see a directive `<directory />` , im not too sure of the replacement needed for your instance, require all granted is the default, check out http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html to try and solve.

Comment: @David **NEVER change `<directory />` to `Require all granted`**. If you dont understand what that section does then do some research. [See point 6](http://www.tecmint.com/apache-security-tips/)

Comment: @RiggsFolly re-read what i said.....i said require all granted is default setting for wamp https://gist.github.com/jitendravyas/6002804, maybe this is not the default file, but i stopped using wamp a couple of years ago so i dont have a version with apache 2.4/ but thank you for the scathing remark.

Comment: @David I re-read. Regardless of version of Apache or OS, you are suggesting allowing any and all access to the root folder of the drive Apache is installed on. Thats a security mistake. With Apache on any environment, you start by denying any access to everything, thats what the `<directory />` section is for. You then only allow Apache access to what it requires access to. Standard practice. This way if you are hacked, the hacker is not automatically allowed to mess with anything on the filesystem. Oh and in WAMPServer or any other enviroment _require all granted_ **is NOT the default**

Comment: @RiggsFolly you are obviously trying to start an argument here....i did not suggest/ say /infer anything that a reasonable person could construe as "change <directory />" ....

Comment: Sorry @David I am not trying to start an arguement. Just trying to stop the OP changing that section of the `httpd.conf` file to something dangerous being as he is trying to open up his apache to the universe.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things that can catch you out while doing this, here are a few I know about.

- You are entering your WAN ip address on a browser inside your router
- Your ISP is actually blocking port 80
- You are in some kind of compound/apartment block and your internet comes through a central entry point and therefore you are behind another router.

***You are entering your WAN ip address on a browser inside your router***

Most SOHO routers do not have the required technology i.e. *loopback*, to allow you to use your WAN ip address inside your router. *SOLUTION:* Tests should be done from outside you router i.e. Go out and use a friends internet connection to see if you can access your site, or use your phone while connected to the ISP network *and not your own wifi*.

***Your ISP is actually blocking port 80***

You can test this by changing the port number that your router is forwwarding to the PC's port 80. To do this do something like this:

Change your routers Port forwarding so that incoming port 8080 is forwarded to you local PC's port 80.

Now again use a internet connection outside your local network or your phones ISP network, and try connection to `YOURIP:8080/`

***You are in some kind of compound/apartment block and your internet comes through a central entry point and therefore you are behind your router and another central router that you have no control over.***

You can normally tell this is the case if your routers WAN ip addres is in one of these ranges i.e. a Private Network Address

```
10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255
172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255
192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255
```

If this is the case, you are probably not going to be able to get around this to your satisfaction. While whoever looks after this central router may claim they are not blocking port 80, of course by virtue of how a router work they are, they are just not actively blocking it. Even if you could get them to Port Forward their routers port 80 to yours, it would only ever work for you, so if 2 people wanted to do this they could not do that without adding some extra hardware to their network, and that is unlikely.

**WARNING**

You will see lots of advice on the web suggesting that changing this section of your `httpd.conf` file may cause Apache to allow you to access it from anywhere:

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

This section should not be changed from the above i.e. totally disallow any access.

The `<Directory />` refers to the root directory of the drive that Apache is installed on.

The recomended mechanism of securing an Apache instance is to disallow any and all access to the `root` folder and all its subfolders, which the above syntax does. You then specifically Allow access only to the folders that Apache actually requires access to, which by default in WAMPServer should be done in this section:

```
<Directory "d:/wamp/www/">

 ...

</Directory>
```

Or in the Virtual Host definitions for each hosted site.

If you change the above to `Require all allowed` what you are saying is: If I get hacked, allow the hacker total access to all the folders on this drive. On unix this may not actually be so terrible as the basic ethos of unix is nobody can access anything unless authorised, so other security mechanisms may well stop access to any folder on the drive. But on Windows where the basic ethos is *its your PC you can do anything you like with it* this can be highly dangerous, and offers hackers a handy attack vector i.e. Apache and once they compromise Apache, this would basically give away the Crown Jewels very easily.

Answer (score 0):

Some isp's will block to prevent you from hosting. You might check with an online port scanner to see if your port 80 is a tually open and forwarding. If you know your setup is right and that your ISP is indeed blocking, you can always port forward a different port and configure apache to listen on that different port.